# assembly language tricky memory addresses

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, att

We are given the prompt (using AT&T ASM)

```
eax      = A

ebx      = B

ecx      = &X

edx      = &Y
```

I understand that (%eax) would grab the data in the memory location at A, but what would doing (%edx) grab? Say for example the call

```
 movl (%edx), %ebx
```

Also

```
movl %eax, (%ecx)
```

Does the first call just replace %ebx's current value with &Y (memory location of y) and the second call replace the data in the memory location &X with the value A?

What about the operation movl %edx, %eda? Does this just move the memory location of &Y into eax?

Thanks

Comment: ecx will contain the address of register `X` which i have no clue what is it from your code !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the 'C' language perspective:

```
eax      = A
```

eax gets a copy of the value of A.

```
ebx      = B
```

ebx gets a copy of the value of B.

```
ecx      = &X
```

ecx gets the address (or memory location) of X.

```
edx      = &Y
```

edx gets the address (or memory location) of y.